# Shell code not responding to while, loop, date

Tags: bash, shell

I commented my while loop in order to test it, but I have a few things wrong with my shell script.

```
name = ""
while [test -z name]; do
echo "Please enter your name:"
read name
done
echo "Hello $name"
echo $date
hour = $(date +H)
if test $hour -ge 9
then
echo "Welcome you are on time again!"
else
echo "You are running behind your scheduled time!"
echo "Employees must be logged in by 9 am."
echo "$name arrived late on $date" >> checkin
fi
```

When `while` is not commented, it does not enter the loop. I assume this has something to do with my conditional. It also does not correctly enter the `if` statement. I'm not sure what the correct format for this is.

The output looks like this:

```
project2: line 1: name: command not found
project2: line 2: [test: command not found
Hello 

project2: line 8: hour: command not found
project2: line 9: [test: command not found
You are running behind your scheduled time!
Employees must be logged in by 9 am.
```

Edit2: Don't know if this is legal but here it goes:

The `while` loop was fixed, thanks guys. Any idea what's going on with my `if` statement?

New code:

```
name = ""
while test -z "$name"
do
   echo "Please enter your name:"
   read name
done
echo "Hello $name"
echo $date
hour = $(date +H)
if test "$hour" -ge "9"
then
  echo "Welcome you are on time again!"
else
  echo "You are running behind your scheduled time!"
  echo "Employees must be logged in by 9 am."
  echo "$name arrived late on $date" >> checkin
fi
```

Output

```
Please enter your name:

Please enter your name:

Please enter your name:
Jack
Hello Jack

project2: line 9: hour: command not found
project2: line 10: test: : integer expression expected
You are running behind your scheduled time!
Employees must be logged in by 9 am.
```

The "Please enter your name" repeat is correct as per the code and imput. Any idea what's going on with the `if` statement? This is bash shell, I probably should have mentioned.

Comment: Variable assignments shouldn't contain spaces around `=`. Statements using `[...]` must have a space after the open and space before the close brackets. Variables must be prefixed with `$`. `while [ -z "$name" ]` should be sufficient to test if name is empty.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the while loop. Any idea what's going on with that if statement?

Comment: It should be `if [ $hour -ge 9 ]`.

Comment: @alvits That didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: It didn't work because the value of `$hour` is `H`. You should change to `hour=$(date +%H)`.

Comment: Ok, that did it. Also fixing the white space. What are the rules on white space? Also, just to really test you :P what is wrong with my `echo $date` as it's written?

Comment: `echo $date` refers to a variable named `date`. But you don't have a variable named date so it will print empty.

Comment: @alvits I didn't realize it was a command. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are most welcome. I'm glad we could help.

Comment: @alvits if you write this up I'll select it as best answer since you helped walk me through it.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable assignments shouldn't contain spaces around `=`.

Statements using `[...]` must have a space after the open and space before the close brackets.

Variables must be prefixed with `$`. `while [ -z "$name" ]` should be sufficient to test if name is empty.

You should change from `hour=$(date +H)` to `hour=$(date +%H)` to actually assign the hour value instead of the letter `H`.

`echo $date` refers to a variable named `date`. But you don't have a variable named `date` so it will print empty.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **revised version of your code that takes full advantage of `bash` features** - all changes are marked with comments:

```
  # NO spaces allowed around `=` in ASSIGNMENTS.
  # Note: By contrast, when `=` or `==` are used 
  #       in CONDITIONALS for COMPARISON, you MUST have spaces around them.
name=""
  # Use `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]` or `test` in bash":
  # It's more robust (mostly no need for quoting) and
  # has more features.
  # You MUST have a space after `[[` and before `]]` (same goes for `[` and `]`).
while [[ -z $name ]]
do
   echo "Please enter your name:"
   read name
done
echo "Hello, $name"
  # There is no `$date` variable. But you can use 
  # COMMAND SUBSTITUTION - `$(...)` to capture the
  # `date` utility's output:
dateNow=$(date)
  # NO spaces around `=`; `H` must be prefixed with `%`
  # to return the hour (thanks, @alvits).
hour=$(date +%H)
  # Use ARITHMETIC EVALUATION - `(( ... ))`
  # for numerical comparisons.
  # You can refer to variables without the $ prefix,
  # and use C-style arithmetic expressions.
if (( hour > 9 ))
then
  echo "Welcome, you are on time again!"
else
  echo "You are running behind your scheduled time!"
  echo "Employees must be logged in by 9 am."
  echo "$name arrived late on $dateNow" >> checkin
fi
```

Comment: This is a great break down of all the issues with the above code in a fantastic format. Thank you for this.

Comment: @JFA: My pleasure; I'm glad you find it helpful.